# OnkeyListener in service class

Tags: android

how can we implement OnkeyListener  or Gesture Detector in service class?its working fine in activity class but does not know how to do it in service class.

Comment: you need to show what you have tried so far.  Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Service class is meant to run background job. The things you are trying is not possible to run on background thread.

Comment: ok lets take example our service is running in background for call detect or sms detect.and during call detect we want to stop text to speech then how it would be possible.

Comment: by using some gestures or key listener

Comment: Then when you receive a call, just push an activity on top. On Activity you can do whatever you want to do :)